# OpenSSL drop-in update in XAMPP for Windows

Tags: openssl, xampp

I've used to update OpenSSL in the past using available Windows binary from this:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

My site's OpenSSL is on 1.1.1a. I've upgraded to the latest 1.1.1b by simply replacing 3 files under "xampp\apache\bin" namely (i stopped Apache while performing this file replacement)

- libcrypto-1_1.dll
- libssl-1_1.dll
- openssl.exe

I was able to start Apache normally without any problems showing signs of a working update.

I was able to validate the OpenSSL version by running openssl.exe in "xampp\apache\bin" and typing 'version'. It showed 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019.

As a side, i was able to update my apache to 2.4.38 in this same server and validate the updated version with phpmyadmin and SSL Labs SSL test.

However in the case of this update of OpenSSL, when i check to validate it in phpmyadmin, it still shows OpenSSL 1.1.1a. Upon trying to check with SSL Labs SSL test on my site, it indeed shows that the current OpenSSL is 1.1.1a still.

Wonder what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0):

My stupidity: i am updating OpenSSL binary on a different folder i made. it's a backup folder.

I am able to update the main binary now xampp\apache\bin and it reflected accordingly.

Comment: In my Xampp 5.6 install, I found openssl.exe in two different folders: C:\xampp\apache\bin and C:\xampp\php\extras\openssl. Perhaps boths must be updated, no?